# PHP code how to list the total value of each user

Tags: php, mysql

table A

```
-----------------
a_id | user     | 
-----------------
1        |adam  |
2        |jose  |
3        |adam  |
4        |adam  |
5        |anne  |
6        |jose  |
```

table B

```
--------------------------------------
b_id | user   | value1 | value2 
--------------------------------------
1    |adam    | 33          | 9
2    |jose    | 46          |88
3    |adam    | 77          |21
4    |adam    | 81          |15
5    |anne    | 11          |67
6    |jose    | 45          |6
```

how can I view the total value of value1 and value2.

example: I want my list view page look like this.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
user  | total value of value1 | total value of value2
---------------------------------------------------------
adam  |191                    | 45
jose  |91                     | 94
anne  |11                     | 67
```

pls. help.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: is this a query or is this a new table?

Comment: **Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service**. Please demonstrate what you have tried and how it is not working (c.f. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). You may want to [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: This is a basic `group by` query.  You should understand the basics of the SQL language if you want to use it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could always try some sort of aggregate query such as the following

```
SELECT user, SUM(value1) AS v1sum FROM B GROUP BY user
```

Comment: All down voters please justify why you have down voted.  This is a correct query to get him what he needs.

Comment: Hi Gary Drocella, i just modified my question, i forgot to include some of table i want to fetch value. can you help me again.

Comment: @blinddevil sure if you mark my answer as correct.

Comment: thank for your correct answer for my first question. but pls. correct my modified question. thank you